# How do I create a scalable NoSQL backend for my use case?

Tags: firebase, database-design, google-cloud-functions, nosql, scalability

I'm working on a personal project that is a dating app. The tech stack I'm using is React Native with Firebase to handle all backend functionalities (auth, firestore, cloud functions).

I want my app to be scalable, but I'll admit that backend isn't a huge strong suit for me. Here are the main features:

- Each user will receive 4 profiles per day that match their preference for 'Men', 'Women', or 'Everyone'. **Location/Proximity or Age is not a part of the preference.** This is similar to Coffee Meets Bagel where each user receives a limited number of 'Bagels' per day.
- When Tammy likes Dave's profile, Tammy will show up on Dave's home screen with a label that reads: "She likes you".
- At that point, Dave can match with Tammy and the two will open a chat window.

My current structure just has 1 collection: `singles`, and it contains documents of every user. For example, I could retrieve all user's details by going to the path `singles/userId`.

One possible solution I have thought about:

- Let's say that the profile circulation will not start until there are 1000 singles on the platform, with at least 40% women and 60% men. I run a scheduled job that creates a collection of Men (150 documents, each with 4 document references), Women (100 documents, each with 4 document references), and a collection of mixed (250 documents, each with 4 document references). When Tammy opens the app today, she will see a random document of the Male group that she has not seen before. When she sees that group, we will write her userId into a subcollection of that document so that we can keep track that she has seen it (and therefore not surface it again). For Dave, we can do the same thing, except show him a random document of 4 women, and write his userId into a subcollection of that document. Then, for every 4 new male sign ups, we can trigger a cloud function to write a new document into the Male collection. And for every 4 new female sign ups, we can write a new document into the Female collection. That way, to the users who want to see men, we have content for 150+ days as a head start. And for women, there is a 100+ day head start, and for those who want to see everyone, there's a 250+ day head start.

Let me know if my proposed solution makes any sense. I am also trying to reduce the number of read/writes in these scheduled jobs and operations.

Comment: Solution to what exactly given what exactly? Where & how are you stuck following what published method? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution of having group documents that reference 4 profile documents would work, but I have the following initial concerns in regards to scalability:

**1. What happens if a user deletes their account?** The reference to their profile would have to be removed from their group. But now there's only 3 in that group, so you'd need to fill the empty spot ASAP. But what if all users are already in a group?

**2. What if it takes weeks or months for a new user to join a group?** Once you begin to scale, this most likely won't be an issue, but what about at the beginning? Users could create an account, and not get any "She likes you" matches for months. From the user's perspective, this is because no one finds them attractive, but in reality it's because not enough users have joined to put them in a group. This could potentially lead to a bad user experience.

**3. It sounds like the group the user is in is permanent. What if they end up in a bad group?** For example, an athlete ends up in a group with a bunch of scholars, and is therefore rejected by association. Their group could misrepresent who they are, which is ok occasionally, but not good if its permanent.

You mentioned that you will be storing the user's id in a subcollection off the groups they have seen. This is a very scalable solution, but not the most cost effective. In order to determine which profiles the user has already viewed, they must perform a collection group query and find all the groups that contains the user's unique id. For a few documents this is ok, but what if the user has viewed thousands of profile groups? That's thousands of reads just to determine which profiles they have already seen. What you could do instead is aggregate all of the viewed users into a single document off the user's profile (you just need to store the uid of the group). Then, when you're close to reaching the 1MB limit per document, create a second document to store more users, etc.

This will require more complex code, but will save a large amount of reads. Whether or not the extra code complexity is worth it is up to you.

An alternative solution could be to store all of your users in your single collection, `singles`, and have an attribute specifying whether they are male, female, etc. as well as their preferences. Then, you can query for 4 profiles based on this attribute and the user's preference when doing their searching. You could then store the viewed profiles in a subcollection off the user document. This would help mitigate the issues outlined above.

Additionally, to restrict to 4 per day, you can set up rate limiting. On the user document keep track of how many profiles they have viewed today. Then run a cron job every day to reset their number of viewed profiles back to 0. All of this would be enforced with your Firestore security rules.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response @Hydra! For the alternative solution you proposed, suppose I want to display these 4 profiles every day at noon. How about a cron job that queries `singles` 4 times and for each profile, compares it to the `viewedProfiles` subcollection on the user to make sure it hasn't been viewed yet. Then I could write these profiles to a new subcollection called `newProfiles` on the user. So for that day, I would display the 4 profiles within `newProfiles`. If the user never logs in and sees these profiles, I can keep them there and save myself some read/writes. Thoughts?

Comment: @SishirMohan You could do that. Make sure you track when a user was last active (a Timestamp when they open the app each day) and incorporate it into your cron job query  so you're not querying for each user every day. You may have thousands of downloads, but even 50% daily retention is uncommonly high and you don't want to be wasting reads querying users that rarely open the app.